# How to provide an @inject constructor param via jest

Tags: angular, jestjs, inject

I have the service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class MyService {
  constructor(private readonly _http: HttpClient, @Inject('env') private env) {}

  getData(): Observable<string> {
    return this._http.get<string>(`${this.env.webApiBaseUrl}data`);
  }
}
```

and the test

```
describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let env = { webApiBaseUrl: 'https://our-nifty-api/' } as any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      providers: [MyService, { provide: env, useValue: env }]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  });
```

Normally I'd mock the httpClient and the response etc. pp. But in this case, the API is to be tested as well. So I have to provide both, the working httpClient, as well as environment parameter.

But how to provide the later?

Comment: See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#injecting-an-object, that shows the whole process.

Comment: I know how to inject the token. But do you mean, I have to repeat the whole process for the test? And can neither use the existing injection-token in the test, nor quickly mock a object with the data needed?

Comment: You're can provide whatever value you like, but you need to use the same *token*. It's `{ provide: token, useValue: value }`, they're not *both* going to be `env`.

Comment: Ehm, isn't that exactly what I do? Token is 'env', well and yes, I named the object of the value to be used as env as well. *scratch head what I miss*

Comment: You've written `env` not `'env'` for the token, and note it's best to use an actual token not a bare string to reduce collision risk.

Comment: *facepalm* Thank you, I was afraid it was such a thing. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the dependency should be a string

```js
describe('MyService', () => {
  let service: MyService;
  let env = { webApiBaseUrl: 'https://our-nifty-api/' } as any;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientModule],
      providers: [
        MyService,
        {
          // HERE IS THE RIGHT DECLARATION
          provide: 'env',
          useValue: env
        }
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(MyService);
  });
```